# Script to strip sections from ELF binaries

Tags: bash, shell, msys

I need to run the following two commands on each file in a directory:

A) First Command:

```
readelf -aW A_FILE | grep Machine
```

where `A_FILE` is the name of a particular file.

The output from the first command looks something like this:

```
Machine:  <unknown>: 0xXXX
```

where `0xXXX` is some hex number.

B) Second command

```
objcopy -I elf64-x86-64 -O elf64-x86-64 -R .source -R .llvmir -R .amdil --alt-machine-code=<Machine> A_FILE A_FILE.STRIPPED
```

where `<Machine>` is the hex number from the first command, and `A_FILE.STRIPPED` is the name of the output file from `objcopy`. (`STRIPPED` is arbitrary, could be any piece of text)

Comment: Should the `0x` be included in the second command, or only the hex digits that follow?

Comment: ...I've also tried to update the question title to be a little less "write-this-for-me!" and to represent what the script actually *does*, since that thing it's doing is development-tool-related and thus topical. :)

Comment: Thanks so much, Charles. Yes, the `0x` should be included in the second command.

Comment: Good deal; including the `0x` is what it does already. BTW -- if you have any trouble with the script I suggested, could you pastebin the output of running it via `bash -x scriptname` somewhere without ads? gist.github.com, ix.io, or similar will do.

Comment: Sure. Am debugging now .  m_line seems to be empty.

Comment: Since you flagged my answer accepted, I assume you found the bug you were hitting; might I ask what it was?

Comment: Thanks again, Sir. The problem was that `machine` had a lower case m, and I had to tweak the regex because there was text before the `machine` at the beginning of the line

Comment: A few critiques -- when using `printf`, variable content should be kept out of format strings; if you have a filename or other piece of content that contains the two characters `\n`, you don't want it changed into a newline -- and in other languages such as C, format string attacks tend to have actual security impact.

Comment: ...consider instead: `printf "readelf output: %s \n\n" "$m_line"`

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip. By the way, is there a way of suppressing the output of objcopy?  I would rather have nothing appear on the screen

Comment: sure; put `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the line (though I'd suggest something like `|| { echo "Objcopy failed!" >&2; }` after it, so you aren't suppressing all knowledge of whether your code is actually working.

Comment: BTW -- as a matter of site etiquette, consider posting your own answer separately, or proposing an edit to someone else's answer, rather than editing an answer into the question -- that way it's on parity with other answers, can be voted and commented on separate from the question, &c.

Comment: Cool:  dev/null worked, but the second option didn't suppress the output

Comment: right, the second option was intended to be used in addition to the redirection to `/dev/null`

Comment: ...so: `objcopy ... >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "Objcopy failed!" >&2; }` will suppress output, but still let you know if there was a failure.

Comment: ahhh, sorry, didn't read carefully.

Comment: I think if you change the regex in your answer to match the one I added to the questions, then I will remove my edits

Comment: Thanks, sorry, but one more change to make it work: If you change the `readelf` line to match my edit, then it seems to be gold.

Comment: BTW -- I understand that `machine` isn't at the front of the line, but is there anything other than whitespace before? Allowing it to be *anywhere* in a line seems likely to have files where it's going to match the wrong line, ie. somewhere in a value field.

Comment: ...so `^[[:space:]]*machine` would be safer, if we can get away with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the whole line reads "The decoding of unwind sections for machine type <unknown>: 0xXXX is not supported"

Comment: Ahh -- that's still enough to do something useful with. (I'm also a little hesitant to assume we'll *never* have four hex digits there; strikes me as safer to capture everything prior to the next space).

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- important, not /bin/sh

# define a regex, in ERE form, to extract the content you want in a match group
re='machine.*(0x[[:xdigit:]]{2,}) '

# iterate over files, putting each in $f
for f in *; do

  # don't operate on files we previously generated
  [[ $f = *.stripped ]] && continue

  # actually run readelf, taking first matching line
  m_line=$(readelf -aW "$f" | egrep -m 1 "$re")

  [[ $m_line =~ $re ]] || continue # check whether we match the regex

  # if we get here, the regex matched; copy the first match group into a variable
  code=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

  # ...and use that variable in calling objcopy
  objcopy -I elf64-x86-64  -O elf64-x86-64 -R .source -R .llvmir -R .amdil \
    --alt-machine-code="$code" \
    "$f" "$f.stripped"
done
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again.